# Changed view Algo from left join to right, can't access DB now

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Using a view I noticed that I wasn't geting all the records I was supposed to, so I went to edit the algo and changed the SQL from a left join to a right join, and clicked save. phpmyadmin then hung with the little loading block. Restarted wamp and I couldn't even log in. Page just sits and loads. So I made I little script to run in the browser to drop my view. This too sat there loading, never actually getting to load the page. I then opened the mysql console (which I know very litle about). After selecting my datagase and trying drop the view, it too never returned anything to confirm the view has been dropped. I then went back to phpmyadmin which now atleast presented me with the log in screen. I logged in and got to the home page where I could select my DB. I clicked on it and it then sits there loading, never to return anything.

I'm not in the mood to loose my entire DB, be it the information is not that important as the design.

How to get to be able to use my DB again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around for awhile I found sqlbuddy. This actually worked somewhat. I could access most of the database. Editing views in SQLbuddy doesn't seem to be available, so I tried dropping the view from here aswell but to no avail, but this lead me to finding the mysql folder in wamp and just deleteing said view FRM file. PHPMYADMIN seems to open my db now with that view no longer there.